# Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-media-capture': CordovaError

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-media-capture': CordovaError: Version of installed plugin: "cordova-plugin-file@5.0.0" does not satisfy dependency plugin requirement "cordova-plugin-file@^6.0.0". Try --force to use installed plugin as dependency.

```
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:557:37
at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30)
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/q/q.js:749:13)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/q/q.js:509:49
at flush (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

Can not install cordova-plugin-media-capture plugin in cordova project

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this is a exact solution, But it's temporary solution to execute.

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-media-capture --force
```

Comment: The real solution is to upgrade your file plugin to `6.0.0`.

Comment: or to install version `2.0.0` of cordova-plugin-media-capture

Comment: Thankyou @n00dl3, I'll try your solution.